# Как изменить значение глобальной переменной внутри функции через параметр

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Пишу такой код: Нужно изменить значение глобальной переменной внутри функции через параметр `variable` что-то не получается, не пинайте если это какая-то простая проблема. Желательно можно без костылей.

```js
'use strict';
function setVar(variable, val) {
variable = val;
}
var myVar;
setVar(myVar, 213);
console.log("Переменная равна "+myVar);
```

## НО!

функция должна взаимодействовать с другими переменными

```js
'use strict';

function setVar(variable, val) {
variable = val;
}
var myVar;
var anothersVar;

setVar(myVar, 213);
setVar(anothersVar, 234);
console.log("Переменная №1 равна "+myVar);
console.log("Переменная №2 равна "+anothersVar);
```

Comment: в таком виде - никак. Если переменная действительно глобальная к ней можно обращаться через `window` или `global` и нет смысла передавать ее через параметр

Comment: _"и нет смысла передавать ее через параметр"_ Если не сложно, объясните.

Comment: если переменная уже доступна как `window.variableName` то проще использовать ее напрямую

Comment: А если нужно чтобы функция взаимодействовала с другими переменными?

Comment: А что ей мешает?

Comment: так же использовать их напрямую. Максимум можно передавать **строку** с именем переменной и используя bracket notation получать уже нужное значение: `window[variableName]`

Comment: Дополнил пример примерно вот так

Comment: @Duoxx, ничего принципиально не поменялось :-)

Comment: Ну я так не понял что нужно сделать.

Comment: `window[variable] = val;`, `setVar("myVar", 213);`

Comment: @Duoxx, ничего, то что ты хочешь - нереализуемо сейчас.

Comment: но лучше заведите объект с полями: `var container = { myVar: undefined, anothersVar: undefined};` и передавайте в функцию его, название свойства и значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит так делать, посмотрите в сторону модульного подхода, AMD,RequireJS, если вы только начали делать проект попробуйте отказаться от вашей идеи с такой функцией и глобальной переменной.
В доказательство что подход обречен на провал, попробуйте выполнить пример кода ниже, и посмотрите как при изменении значения параметра функции у вас произойдет внештатная ситуация.

```js
'use strict';
function setVar(variable, val) {
window[variable] = val;
}
var myVar;
setVar("location", 'ya.ru');
console.log("Переменная равна "+myVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такое, только здесь приходится в качестве строки передавать

```js
'use strict';
function setVar(variable, val) {
window[variable] = val;
}
var myVar;
setVar("myVar", 213);
console.log("Переменная равна "+myVar);
```